# Connecting to remote aerospike server - Community edition

Tags: python-2.7, aerospike

I am a beginner with aerospike with Python client. I have an aerospike [build - 3.9.1.1] installed in a google instance.
How can I connect to the server from another instance?

I tried the following in shell and wouldn't budge:

```
import aerospike
config = {'hosts': [('xx.mmm.nn.oo', 3000)]}
# the IP from ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
client = aerospike.client(config)
client.connect()
```

This yields exception as below:

```
ClientError: (-1L, 'Failed to connect', 'src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c', 459)
```

> In the remote I tried the following:

This works fine:

```
asinfo -v "namespaces"
```

Also this works when I do:

```
telnet xx.mmm.nn.oo 3003
....
namespaces
...
```

Going desperate, I have tried setting `access-address` in the local with the IP of the server [xx.mmm.nn.oo] and that didn't work either!

Please help folks!

Comment: Are you able to do asinfo -h xx.mmm.nn.oo -v namespaces from the host where you are running the client from?

Comment: from the same machine it works but on the client it gives:
`request to  10.132.0.9 : 3000  returned error`

should there be any configuration to allow such a connection?

Comment: Is the client host in the same Google project? Can it ping that IP address? And finally is port 3000 reachable from that machine? (You may need to make some changes in your google instance/project firewall settings to enable communication on port 3000).

Comment: Yes.. I fixed the issue.. i had to allow connections by editing the iptables:

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT

Comment: Glad to hear. I posted it in the answer, maybe will get me some points!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue apparently resolved by allowing connections by editing the iptables:

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT –